# Botão OK do Teclado evento Android

Tags: android, teclado

Boa tarde galera mais uma vez pedindo ajuda. Gostaria de saber com faço para pegar o evento do botão OK do teclado. Exemplo se tenho um login e quero que ao clicar em ok ele tenha o mesmo efeito que teria o botão entrar da minha aplicação.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Eu costumo fazer dessa forma:

```
<EditText
    // Demais atributos do seu EditText
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:lines="1"
    android:inputType="textImeMultiLine"
    android:imeActionLabel="@string/pronto"
    android:imeOptions="actionDone" />
```

Sendo:

- `maxLines` e `lines` sendo 1, pois senão ele poderia sobrepor o botão de quebra de linha, por isso ele só pode ter uma linha.
- `imeOptions` o código referente ao botão de Ok/Done (No Kindle Fire dizem que é `actionGo`, ai teria que trocar a verificação do `actionId` para `EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_GO`).
- `inputType` precisa ser `textImeMultiline`.
- `imeActionLabel` o texto que aparece no botão.

Na sua `Activity` ou `Fragment`, o tratamento do evento deve ser dessa forma:

```
EditText edit = findViewById(...);

edit.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
        if(event != null && KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER == event.getKeyCode() || actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
            confirmAction();
        }

        return false;
    }
});
```

Só uma observação, me parece que por experiência própria esse código só funciona para o teclado padrão do `Google` e do `Android`. Não consegui fazer funcionar no **SwiftKey** por exemplo, dizem que os applicativos de terceiros não respeitam o botão de `Ime Action`.